# File ended while scanning use of \next, while using \begin{comment} on macro definition

Tags: macros, errors, optional-arguments, technical-environment

On the question [How to replace a command with a dummy one?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387394/how-to-replace-a-command-with-a-dummy-one) I learned to do:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\newif\ifdebug
\debugtrue
% \debugfalse

\ifdebug
\makeatletter

\@ifundefined{includegraphics}
{
    \newcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{ includegraphics \detokenize{#1} \detokenize{#2} }
}{}

\makeatother
\else\fi

\begin{document}

\sloppy
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pictures/ex01}

\end{document}
```

Which generate the following PDF file:

[image]

So now would like to comment out the contents of the command, however when I added `\begin{comment}` & `\end{comment}` on `\newcommand{\includegraphics}`:

```
\@ifundefined{includegraphics}
{
    \newcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{ \begin{comment} includegraphics \detokenize{#1} \detokenize{#2} \end{comment} }
}{}
```

I got the error:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ./test2.tex

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Emergency stop.
<*> ./test2.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

How can the contents of the command be throw away?

---

Related:

1. [Wrap mdframed environment into a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351012/wrap-mdframed-environment-into-a-command)
2. [How to write an environment wrapping document environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83501/how-to-write-an-environment-wrapping-document-environment)
3. [Beamer - ! File ended while scanning use of \next](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225581/beamer-file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-next)
4. [File ended while scanning use of \next](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246147/file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-next)
5. ["Runaway argument? File ended while scanning use of \abx@aux@page."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299191/runaway-argument-file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-abxauxpage)
6. [Use of the comment package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129153/use-of-the-comment-package)
7. [How to write hidden notes in a LaTeX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/how-to-write-hidden-notes-in-a-latex-file)
8. [Comment package not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/comment-package-not-working)