# Hiding/commenting out a nested table

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, technical-environment

Continuing the question [File ended while scanning use of \next, while using \begin{comment} on macro definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387437/file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-next-while-using-begincomment-on-macro-def) another example would be when there is a table inside the redefined command redefined by:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\newif\ifdebug
\debugtrue
% \debugfalse

\ifdebug
\makeatletter

\@ifundefined{resizebox}
{
    \newcommand{\resizebox}[3][]{ resizebox \detokenize{#1} \detokenize{#2} \detokenize{#2} }
}{}

\makeatother
\else\fi

\begin{document}

\sloppy
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
{
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.6cm}|p{6.0cm}|p{2.25cm}|p{3.40cm}}

       \textbf{Investigação} & \textbf{Insumos} & \textbf{Sistema} & \textbf{Produtos}  \\
        \hline
       Meta-nível            & Filosofia        & Epistemologia    & Paradigma  \\
        \hline
       Nível                 & Paradigmas       & Ciencia          & Teorias    \\
        \hline
       inferior              & Modelos          & Pratica          & problemas  \\

    \end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

The table seems to be rendered anyways, but the `resizebox` command parameter was printed on the top:

[image]

How to stop the table from being rendered/draw, i.e., comment it out while nested on `resizebox` command redefined?

Would be the only option to redefine the table environment, to for it to be treated as plain-text or hide/comment out the table contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

use of `resizebox` is tricky. better is determined table width with use of `tabular` or `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}% i haven brazil label

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                                >{\hsize=0.22\hsize}X
                                >{\hsize=0.34\hsize}X
                                >{\hsize=0.22\hsize}X
                                >{\hsize=0.22\hsize}X
                             @{} }
    \toprule
\textbf{Investigação}   & \textbf{Insumos}  & \textbf{Sistema}  & \textbf{Produtos} \\
    \midrule
Meta-nível              & Filosofia         & Epistemologia     & Paradigma         \\
Nível                   & Paradigmas        & Ciencia           & Teorias           \\
inferior                & Modelos           & Pratica           & problemas         \\
    \bottomrule
```

*note*:
it is not clear what second column had to be wider then others. see, if reusl, when all have the same width is acceptable. in this case the begining of `tabularx` is simpler:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} XX XX @{} }
```

and table looks like this:

[image]